# If javascript is disabled move the linked page orelse show a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, onclick

I wrote this script for javascript disabled browser.

Here is HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onClick="jstest();">Google</a>
```

Here is Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jstest() {
    alert("Success");
    // show popup
    return false;
    };
</script>
```

If javascript is enabled it should alert a popup showing success. And if it is disabled it should move to google page. I was told to do this by a friend. It works on jsFiddle.net. But not working if i try to do this in my work.

It shows popup when i click and when i close popup it moves onto google page.

I want it to stay on the same page. I dont want it to move on link page.

It should move only if javascript is disabled.

What have i done wrong in this script?

Thank You,

Kishore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onClick="return jstest();">
```

The return within the onClick should confirm that the return false from your function should bubble up to the hyperlink's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include that script *after* the element it tries to assign the `onclick` handler to. Or wrap that code in an `onload` handler. Otherwise the JS executes before the element has been parsed so `getElementById("goo")` doesn't find it.

By the way, you don't need an inline html attribute `onclick` as well as assigning a handler in your JS. The attribute is trying to call a global function called `jstest()` which doesn't exist in your code. You could remove the `document.getElementById("goo").onclick =` part and just declare the function with the same name as used in the inline html attribute `onclick`.

I would guess it works on jsfiddle.net because by default jsfiddle wraps your code in an `onload` handler (you can change this via the panel on the left).

Comment: It works now thank you. But it move onto link page (google page) when i close the popup. I dont want the code to do that. I want it to stay in the same page.

Comment: Thank u nnnnnn for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you have an onclick embedded in your tag

jQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $("#goo").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      // Do whatever you want here
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#goo").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Success");
    });
});
```

Hope this helps

Here is a [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rogerblake/792qP/)